# Composer: "Repository type is not registered: git"

Tags: git, doctrine-orm, composer-php, symfony4

Out of the blue, my Composer is throwing a fit when I try and install a local repository (having worked perfectly for the past 3 months) using `composer install`

The error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException] Repository type is not registered: git
```

The offending block in the composer.json file:

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@github.com:/xxx/yyy.git"
    }
],
```

I've tried completed removing and re-installing composer and changing the 'type' from 'git' to 'github' and 'vcs' as per the official docs. Nothing has helped so far.

Comment: Which version of Composer you're using? `composer --version`

Answer (score 1):

My colleague has informed me that this is the cause...

https://github.com/symfony/flex/pull/377

Answer (score 0):

Try with `vcs` instead of `git`, as example:

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:/xxx/yyy.git"
    }
  ],
```

[More info here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories)

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

like already mentioned, `symfony/flex` seemed to be broken (v. v1.0.81?)
and composer uses `symfony-flex-plugin`

so `composer install` was working only with the parameter `--no-plugins`

when i used that:
a new flex version was installed and my project dependencies where installed, but the absence of plugins luckily failed afterwards only with `symfony-cmd: command not found`

But since 'flex' was updated `composer install` was working fine again (plugins working too)